# How to get the redirected url in golang

Tags: go, redirect

When I request the url_a, the server will redirect the request to the url_b.

How to get the redirected url_b when I do the request in golang?

Answer (score 2):

The default HTTP client follows redirects. If you want to handle redirects yourself or simply not follow them, set the http `Client` `CheckRedirect` function:

```
cli := &http.Client{
    CheckRedirect: func(req *Request, via []*Request) error { 
        return http.ErrUseLastResponse;
    },
}

cli.Get(...)
```

When you return `ErrUseLastResponse`, the `GET` method will return the last response unmodified.